# Check if json data length doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to build a product compare module with a bootstrap 4 dropdown. 
Inside that dropdown there are products listed with some info. When you click delete at a product then a function called `updateCompare`is loaded. This function loads json data and updates the compare list. This all works fine except when there's only one product listed. When I click delete on the last item then the function throw errors.

So what I have is this:

```
function updateCompare(){
    $.get(compareUrl + '?format=json', function(e) {
        products = [];
        $.each(e.compare.products, function(index, product) {
         // ... code to build products ....
          products.push(productHtml);
        });
        products.join('');
        $('#compare .compare-inner .empty').html(products);
  })
}

$(function(){
// delete product from compare
  $(document).on("click", "#compare .remove", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var vid = $(this).closest('.item').data('vid');
    var url = compareUrl + 'delete/' + vid;
     $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST", 
      url: url, 
      success: function(msg){ 
        updateCompare()
      }
    }); 
  });
});
```

The error I get is `TypeError: a is undefined`

What I tried in `updateCompare` is things like:

```
function updateCompare(){
    $.get(compareUrl + '?format=json', function(e) {
        products = [];
        if(e.compare.products.length > 1 ){
         $.each(e.compare.products, function(index, product) {
         // .... code to build products
         });
        } else {
         $('#compare').dropdown("dispose")
        }
```

But above throws an error like: `TypeError: e.compare.products is undefined`

Also I tried:

```
if(e.compare.products.length > 1 || e.compare.products != NULL || e.compare.products != false ){
```

But that throws an error `e.compare.products is undefined`.

I've been working on this way too long so perhaps I miss something very simple.  I just can't see it anymore :(

Any help greatly appreciated!!

**As per request**

Empty compare json:

```
{
   "compare":false
}
```

JSON with 3 products:

```
{
   "compare":{
      "products":[
         {
            "id":39687158,
         },
         {
            "id":39687161,
         },
         {
            "id":39687164,
         }
      ]
   },

}
```

Comment: can you please show us the json data? also where did you use variable a which is undefined?

Comment: @schildi: I've updated the question with JSON. With your idea I also tried `e.compare.products != false`. But that also gives `TypeError: a is undefined`. I don't know exactly what you mean with `where did you use variable a which is undefined`?!?!

Comment: @Meules schldi means - in your question you wrote "The error I get is TypeError: a is undefined"...but in your code sample there's no variable called `a`. Obviously in order to resolve the error you need to find that variable and then find out why it hasn't been given a value.

Comment: @Meules Anyway, based on your JSON, instead of `if(e.compare.products.length > 1 ){` you might be better doing `if (e.compare != false) {` . Clearly, in the "empty JSON" case you mention, there is no property called "products" which is a child of "compare". It does not exist...which is why when you try to use it in code you're told that `e.compare.products is undefined`. Being undefined means the variable does not exist or has no value. Logically then, you can't ask for its length, because you're asking for the length of nothing. So...the error is actually quite simple when you think about it.

Comment: @schildi, @ADyson: Man!! Like I said been too long working on this. `if (e.compare != false) {` get rid of the errors. Only thing left is to destroy that dropdown. Thx to both!!